# object has no attribute 'clean_data' error

Tags: python, django

I keep on getting a object has no attribute when cleaning my data. The error only occurs when I try to POST to the form to register a user.

While I could have used the django built in registration view and form, I decided to use a built one since I wanted to make it easier to use a extended custom user model later.
views:

```
def register(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if user_form.is_valid():

        new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)

        new_user.set_password(
            user_form.clean_data['password'])

        new_user.save()

        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)

        return render(request, 
            'account/register_done.html', 
            {'new_user':new_user})
else:
    user_form = UserRegistrationForm()

return render(request, 
                'registration.html', 
            {'user_form': user_form})
```

forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm   


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', 
        widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name',
        'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.clean_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']
```

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `cleaned_data`

Comment: Yes, yes I was...@Gocht